# How to convert text to speech in python

Tags: python, text-to-speech, speech

I would like to now how to convert text to speech in python.

In .NET i used

```
Dim SAPI

Msg = 'Hi this is a test'

SAPI = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
SAPI.Speak(Msg)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by [pyttsx](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx) module. it uses default MS speech recognition system.

```
import pyttsx

engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say("Your Message")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 2):

I know its real late to answer here, But I thought I would post here since I have solution based on `TTS` conversion using `SAPI` in `python`, which was OP's original question.

This may be useful for anyone else looking for solution using `SAPI` in `python`.

```
from win32com.client import constants, Dispatch

Msg = "Hi this is a test"

speaker = Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")  #Create SAPI SpVoice Object
speaker.Speak(Msg)                  #Process TTS
del speaker                         #Delete speaker object and free up memory
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I change its voice to female voice ( also language )

Comment: I haven't personally done it, but based on research, It may be possible to change voice by setting `Sapi.SpVoice.Voice` property. Please refer to SAPI documentation here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10121

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyttsx3
speaker=pyttsx3.init()
speaker.say("Your message")
speaker.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# pip install pywin32
# pip install pyttsx3
 
import pyttsx3

pyttsx3.speak('Hello Woeld')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is Male's and Female's voices function created by myself.
Just define a file name and save it.
Now you can import it into another file and reuse it again and again.

```
pip install pyttsx3
```

---

```
import pyttsx3
def femaleVoice(text):
    print("Program : "+text)
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[-1].id)
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def maleVoice(text):
    print("Program : "+text)
    pyttsx3.speak(text)

femaleVoice("There we go.")#Text
maleVoice("There we go.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the [gTTS](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) module. It converts the text to speech.
The second module you have to use is [playsound](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) to play the converted text.

```
    from gtts import gTTS #pip install gtts
    import playsound #pip install playsound
    import os

    my_aud = gTTS("hello how are you") #converts the text into speech
    my_aud.save('demo.mp3') #save the file with .mp3 extension
    playsound('demo.mp3') #to play it
    os.remove('demo.mp3')
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you have a good processor/GPU, you can use this HuuggingFace
> transformer code for the best free results! Perhaps the quality is
> better than gtts!

```
# Get dependencies
# pip install soundfile transformers datasets sentencepiece

from transformers import SpeechT5Processor, SpeechT5ForTextToSpeech, SpeechT5HifiGan
from datasets import load_dataset
import torch
import random
import string
import soundfile as sf

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

# load the processor
processor = SpeechT5Processor.from_pretrained("microsoft/speecht5_tts")
# load the model
model = SpeechT5ForTextToSpeech.from_pretrained("microsoft/speecht5_tts").to(device)
# load the vocoder, that is the voice encoder
vocoder = SpeechT5HifiGan.from_pretrained("microsoft/speecht5_hifigan").to(device)
# we load this dataset to get the speaker embeddings
embeddings_dataset = load_dataset("Matthijs/cmu-arctic-xvectors", split="validation")

# speaker ids from the embeddings dataset
speakers = {
    'clb': 2271,  # US female
    'slt': 6799   # US female
}

def save_text_to_speech(text, speaker=None):
    # preprocess text
    inputs = processor(text=text, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
    if speaker is not None:
        # load xvector containing speaker's voice characteristics from a dataset
        speaker_embeddings = torch.tensor(embeddings_dataset[speaker]["xvector"]).unsqueeze(0).to(device)
    else:
        # random vector, meaning a random voice
        speaker_embeddings = torch.randn((1, 512)).to(device)
    # generate speech with the models
    speech = model.generate_speech(inputs["input_ids"], speaker_embeddings, vocoder=vocoder)
    if speaker is not None:
        # if we have a speaker, we use the speaker's ID in the filename
        output_filename = f"{speaker}-{'-'.join(text.split()[:6])}.mp3"
    else:
        # if we don't have a speaker, we use a random string in the filename
        random_str = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters+string.digits, k=5))
        output_filename = f"{random_str}-{'-'.join(text.split()[:6])}.mp3"
    # save the generated speech to a file with 16KHz sampling rate
    sf.write(output_filename, speech.cpu().numpy(), samplerate=16000)
    # return the filename for reference
    return output_filename

# generate speech with a US female voice
save_text_to_speech("Python is my favorite programming language", speaker=speakers["slt"])

# a challenging text with all speakers
text = """In his miracle year, he published four groundbreaking papers.
These outlined the theory of the photoelectric effect, explained Brownian     motion,
introduced special relativity, and demonstrated mass-energy     equivalence."""

for speaker_name, speaker in speakers.items():
    output_filename = save_text_to_speech(text, speaker)
    print(f"Saved {output_filename}")
# random speaker
output_filename = save_text_to_speech(text)
print(f"Saved {output_filename}")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want access to a ton of voices. We have over 500.

Here's a snippet

```
python
import apiaudio 
import os


apiaudio.api_key = os.environ['APIKEY']
first_track = apiaudio.Orchestrator.create_audio(scriptText="Hello World my first audio track", 
                                                 voice="Ryan",
                                                 soundTemplate="jakarta")
print(first_track)
```

You just need a FREE api key. Have a look at http://www.api.audio

Answer (score -1):

Stack overflow policy do not recommend user to promote or advertise tools, so I decided to tell you a method.

**I think you can create a TTS by yourself using pure python:**

1. Text map to 64k mp3 audio
2. Use ",." symbol to separate text, so you get less repeated text data
3. When you got 1GB of data, you get a well functioned TTS

> You could even use speech recognition to collect audio to text dict data.

> By using this method, you could get almost 100% accurate TTS for your voice